# Sourcing commands from csv

Tags: bash, shell, csv, command-line, terminal

I am trying to execute multiple commands which are defined in a .csv file. So every line in the .csv is a command that can be executed on bash/terminal (but each line differs by the input file).

When I tried

```
source <path to csv file>
```

Only the last command, or last line of the .csv worked. With the previous commands, it didn't seem to be able to locate the input files.

When I made a file in shell and copied+pasted the exact commands from .csv :

```
nano commandfile

<commands pasted from .csv>

source commandfile
```

it now worked for all lines of the file.

Could someone more knowledgeable than me explain why the first example didn't work? How can I get terminal to be able to source all the commands in a .csv? Copy+paste into nano texteditor is fine but it doesn't seem very... refined.

Thanks!

Comment: Check that you don't have Windows line endings in the original commandfile by using cat -v. Also, I expect the commas in the original file to cause issues. Maybe you passed the commands without commas in the second case?

Comment: How can we reproduce this issue? There is nothing in the question that we can copy-paste to our terminals

Comment: @granny : Aside from the other comments given here, note that if this is **really** a file in CSV format, it won't be executable in this way, even if it consists of only a single column. One of the reason is the way CSV defines the formatting of cell content, which contains the field separator.

Comment: Generally CSV stands for a comma-separated-values file which does not contain commands. So just sourcing that file will most of the time result in failures of the shell script. I see now two options **(1)** Does CSV have the same meaning for you as for the rest of us and **(2)** if it does have the same meaning, don't you want to load commands from a particular column? If so, could you give us an example of your CSV?

Comment: thanks everyone for the suggestions - turns out there were windows line endings (^M) at the end of all the commands. When I removed them, and tried sourcing the csv again, all lines worked.

Comment: While you may have gotten this to work for you in this case, I can't think of a valid reason why you would want to use a "CSV file" in this way - [CSV files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) are meant for storing data, not instructions.